# Problems saving and retrieving numbers

Tags: swift, core-data, numbers

I am working on an app that uses CoreData.

I am strong numbers and retrieving them, but when i store more than one field it only shows the last field with the number but a 0 in all the others. below is my codes.

to store them...

```
 let CWConvert = Double(CWeight.text!)
                            storeTranscription18CW(pageText: (CWConvert)!, textFileUrlString: "cWeight")
                                savePlus += 1


                            let TWConvert = Double(TWeight.text!)
                            storeTranscription18TW(pageText: (TWConvert)!, textFileUrlString: "tWeight")
```

and...

```
        func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    _ = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return DataController().managedObjectContext
}


func storeTranscription18CW (pageText: Double, textFileUrlString: String) {


    let context = getContext()

    //retrieve the entity that we just created
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TextInputs", in: context)

    let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    // set the entity values

        transc.setValue(pageText, forKey: "cWeight")

    //save the object
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }
}


func storeTranscription18TW (pageText: Double, textFileUrlString: String) {
    let contexta = getContext()

    //retrieve the entity that we just created
    let entitya =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TextInputs", in: contexta)

    let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entitya!, insertInto: contexta)

    // set the entity values

        transc.setValue(pageText, forKey: "tWeight")

    //save the object
    do {
        try contexta.save()
        print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }
}
```

and to retrive.

```
    func getTranscriptions18CW () {
    //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity
    let fetchRequesta: NSFetchRequest<TextInputs> = TextInputs.fetchRequest()
    do {
        //go get the results
        let searchResults18CW = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequesta)

            for transa in searchResults18CW as [NSManagedObject] {
                if let resulta = transa.value(forKey: "cWeight") {
                    if let stra = resulta as? String {
                        CWeight.text = stra
                    }else {
                        CWeight?.text = "\(resulta)"
                    }
                }
            }
            //get the Key Value pairs (although there may be a better
    }catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
}

func getTranscriptions18TW () {
    //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TextInputs> = TextInputs.fetchRequest()
    do {
        //go get the results
        let searchResults18TW = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

            for trans in searchResults18TW as [NSManagedObject] {
                if let result = trans.value(forKey: "tWeight") {
                    if let str = result as? String {
                        TWeight.text = str
                    }else {
                        TWeight?.text = "\(result)"

                }
            }
            //get the Key Value pairs (although there may be a better way to do that...
        }
    }catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

i have tried different names but get the same it only shows the last one as the real number if i moment out the last one then the first shows the real value.

[image: The text fields]

Comment: So are you trying to display multiple values of tWeight to the same text field? Is this in a tableview?

Comment: Hi, No this is 2 different Text fields when i have them set as strings in Core data and set a any instead of double then it works but i need them to be Double because i want to convert the number that comes in with math

Comment: Why don't you have both numbers in the same save function? When you save into two different functions you create a new row for each save.  So when you save Current weight 3 then Target gets saved as a nil.  Same thing happens when you save target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this to save so that you are saving both in the same row.

```
func storeTranscription18TW () {
    let contexta = getContext()

    //retrieve the entity that we just created
    let entitya =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TextInputs", in: contexta)

    let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entitya!, insertInto: contexta)

    // set the entity values
    transc.setValue(CWConvert, forKey: "cWeight") // Note the change from pageText
    transc.setValue(TWConvert, forKey: "tWeight") // Note the change from pageText

    //save the object
    do {
       try contexta.save()
       print("saved!")
       } catch let error as NSError  {
          print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       } catch {

   }
}
```

Then when you do a get they would both be done in the same function as well.

Comment: I have already tried this and it saves the same value of the last one inputed and saves it to both fields instead of them having separate numbers

Comment: with the pageText change it gives an error saying unresolved identifier cWeightText and same on tWeight

Comment: with the new update it now shows 0 int he fields again

Comment: I figured the problem with your solution i had to also declare the CWConvert  and TWConvert above the ransc.setValue(CWConvert, forKey: "cWeight").  Now it all works thank you for your help on this. much appreciated, also saved me so much code because i had 8 text fields putting them in one function worked great the way you showed. and the numbers are saving